# A single linux shell script executes multiple commands, and the commands are written into multiple shell scripts and executed in sequence. Total time

Tags: linux, shell, data-export

I am a linux beginner , I am trying to import and export data using shell script. The data about **60,000,000** rows. When I execute the import and export commands separately from the command line, I find that perform very well. But I merged commands into a single shell script and the performance slowed down, I tried many times and I don't know why.

**The following is the information of my test environment**

- System version information

  ```
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
  ```
- shell script content

> Export_from_POSTGRES_lineitem.sh

```
psql postgres://postgres:rdpadmin@192.168.120.73/sf10 -c  "\copy lineitem to './Export_from_POSTGRES_lineitem.csv' with DELIMITER '|';" 2>&1
```

> Load_to_MYSQL_lineitem.sh

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -uroot -prdpuser --database test_db -e "load data local infile './Export_from_POSTGRES_lineitem.csv' into table lineitem fields terminated by '|';" 2>&1
```

---

What I'm doing is exporting a table on a postgres database on another machine to a local csv file and then importing the csv file into my local mysql database. Before executing the export script, I will manually delete the existing local csv file. The csv file exported each time is about 8.6GB. Before importing to mysql, I will use ** TRUNCATE ** to clear the original data in the table. I make sure it's a clean environment before each test.

When I execute the **Export** script alone, it takes about **4 minutes**.

When I execute the **Load** script alone, it takes about **5 minutes 30 seconds**.

I have tested it many times, and the time is only within 20 seconds.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8hdn.png)

But when I merged the two scripts and executed them, I found that the time consuming increased.

- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1WWU.png)
- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lcN.png)

I don't know what caused this, I hope I have described the problem I encountered in detail, and I hope to get your suggestions. If other information is needed, I will give it in time.

Comment: Just checking but are you truncating the MySQL table before loading it? and if so which?

Comment: Yes, if the table has data ,I use `TRUNCATE test_db.lineitem` to empty the data in the table each time before load data into the mysql `lineitem` table.If there is no data in the table, I will do nothing.

Comment: I've tried at least four times, executing both commands through single script, the export from postgres takes normal time, while executing the command imported into MySQL is always two minutes slower than executing the import statement alone, although the overall The functionality works, but I would like to know what is causing this problem.